# "babel-node" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: javascript, babel

intentando volver a un proyecto que tenia hecho de hace unos pocos meses, me encuentro con un problema con babel, despues de intentar solucionarlo desde stackoverflow y mas paginas, no encontré el fallo.
Estoy empezando un nuevo proyecto en el que estoy intentado usar babel, pero me sigue dando problemas.
Os dejo mi archivo package.json aquí

```
{
  "name": "MEVN-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node src/app.js --exec",
    "dev": "nodemon src/app.js",
    "devbabel": "nodemon src/app.js --exec babel-node",
    "test": "jest --runInBand"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "forever": "^3.0.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.13",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.20",
    "underscore": "^1.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/node": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.16",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7"
  }
}
```

Aqui os dejo mi index.js

```
'use strict'

import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cors from 'cors';
//Esto nos sirve para que nos diga donde esta nuestra ruta por defecto configura y sepa donde esta el archivo que le digamos
//en el middelware
import path from 'path';

//Settings
require('./database');
const app = express();
/* require('./config/passport'); */
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//Middelwares
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Routes
app.use('/api', require('./routes/taskRoute'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/userRoute'));
app.use('/api/login', require('./routes/loginRoute'));

//Middelware para Vue.js router modo history -----MUY IMPORTANTE ESTE MIDDELWARE DE VUE, SIEMPRE DESPUES DE LAS RUTAS
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
//History debe ir siempre encima del archivo static public, 
app.use(history());
//Aqui configuramos el path y le decimos que la direcion de la carpeta estatica, es public
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public')));

//Port listening
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server on port', app.get('port'));
});

module.exports = { app, server };
```

El error es el que pone en el titulo, no reconoce como comando interno o externo.
Y en ocasiones me sale otro error que dice que estoy intentando usar una version de Babel 6.0.... y que debería usar la version 7......
y realmente como podeis ver, tengo instaladas las ultimas versiones de babel.

EDITADO//
Ahora mismo me acaba de dar este error

import express from 'express';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: En dependencias está especificada la version 6.0 de babel, lo puedes ver en tu `package.json` como: `"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",`

Comment: Gracias por la observación y rapida respuesta, lo acabo de eliminar, me sigue dando el error

Comment: ¿A qué te refiereses con que lo *eliminaste*? ¿Hiciste un upgrade? ¿Borraste la dependencia del JSON?

Comment: Como veo que estas utilizando propiedades básicas de esNext ya no es necesario usar babel, con node 14.X utilizando el flag --harmony puedes utilizar propiedades de es6 y deno (v8) como await on top level y claro import y exports. Para esto también deberías poner en tu package.json el type: module y puedes usar import y export.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a los dos. Fran habia hecho un remove del package Json y a Denyn muchas gracias, no sabía que ya no era necesario. Gracias por el aporte chicos